# Object Orientated has a relationship calling owner method

Tags: class, oop

Let's say I have a library class and a book class that is a one to many 'has-a' relationship (i.e. a Libary has many Books). If I have a method in the Book class called isRead() which is called when the book is read, how can I call a method in the library when all books have been read e.g. libraryRead()? From the library class, how can it determine when all books have been read?

Is there a way that when isRead() in the Book class is called, a method in the Library class is called as well such as newBookRead()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in the `Library` which will be called inside `Book` class, for example `bookHasBeenReadCallback`

```
class Library {
    List<Book> books;
    int readCounter = 0;

    public void bookHasBeenReadCallback(){
        readCounter++;
        if (readCounter == books.size()){
            //all book has been read
        }
    }
}
```

The book class can accept Library as a parameter within its constructor. You can call the `bookHasBeenReadCallback` inside the isRead() method.

Note that you may like to add `boolean readFlag` to prevent `bookHasBeenReadCallback()` called more than once for the same book

```
class Book {
    Library library;
    boolean readFlag = false;

    public Book(Library library){
        this.library = library;
    }

    boolean isRead(){
        if (readFlag){
            return true;
        }
        readFlag = true;
        library.bookHasBeenReadCallback();
        return readFlag;
    }
}
```